# AJAX Change function

Tags: php, ajax

I have a AJAX change function in my code..which works fine..in local server..i.e WAMP...but doesn't execute on remote server...where might be the problem???
i checked the version of server php too...

my code..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".course").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxfile.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".book").html(html);

} 
});

});

});
</script>

Course :
<select name="course" class="course">
<option selected="selected">--Select Course--</option>
<?php

include "db.php"; 
$sql ="select * from Courses";
$query=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$id=$row['Cid'];
$name=$row['Course'];
echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
} ?>

</select>

Album :
<select name="book" class="book">
<option selected="selected">--Select Book--</option>
</select>
```

ajaxfile.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql ="select BookTitle from bookcode where Courses='$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$data=$row['BookTitle'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you look in the browser's console?

Comment: `select BookTitle from bookcode` - `$row['id']` and `$id` will not appear since you did not select it in your query. And there's no reference to an `id` anywhere.

Comment: *You talkin' to me Sam?* - @JayBlanchard seeing we're the only ones in here.

Comment: Ajax does not have a change method. Ajax refers to the XMLHttpRequest object, not JavaScript in general. Add an error handler to your Ajax call and see if the call fails. Add debugging statements to see if the change event is being triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
```

change it to this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
```

Why? because in ajax you are then passing the ID not the name: `var dataString = 'id='+ id;`

Comment: Thx...This was one of the mistake...and other mistake was case sensitive...i.e...in local server..it would accept any case..table name..but in remote server...case sensitive was the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have some sort of access issue to ajaxfile.php

You may try to set the url to "/ajaxfile.php" if it's located in the main directory accessible on the web or with the complete path like "http://'put your url here'/ajaxfile.php"